# Using .match to find in string returning weird results

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of keys and an array of their corresponding values. I have been running a `forEach` method on the array of values to get their corresponding keys. Here is my array of keys and values I am getting from my JSON file:

```js
keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

// result:
["Year", "month", "Day", "date", "product", "Social_Platform", "type", "p_total", "m_p_total", "d_p_total", "u_total", "m_U_total", "d_U_total", "v_total", "m_v_total", "d_v_total"]
```

```js
vals = Object.values(data[0]);

// result
[2020, 1, 29, 1580256000000, "Chocos", "Twitter", "candy", 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

forEach Method:

```
vals.forEach(k => {
  if (typeof k == 'string') {
    corres_key = Object.keys(data[0]).find(key => data[0][key] === k);
    arr.push(corres_key);
  } else {
    corres_key = Object.keys(data[0]).find(key => data[0][key] === k);
    if (corres_key.match(/date/gi) || corres_key.match(/dt/gi) || corres_key.match(/YEAR/gi) || corres_key.match(/DAY/gi) || corres_key.match(/MONTH/gi)) {
      console.log(corres_key);
      arr.push(corres_key);
    }
  }
});
```

My result:

```
Year
month
Day
date
month (6 times)
```

Why is my month getting printed 6 times? It is not doing that with any other value. Just month. Why is that happening?

I am trying to get all the keys that have string values and out of what is left I want to find all the date (`date, dt, year, day, month`) corresponding keys

Comment: its vals, sorry my bad. I just edited the code

Comment: Please provide a [mre]; All you really need to provide is `data` with a single object in it (so that `data[0]` works). If you want to wrap it up in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar), that would be even better.

Comment: The problem is because your code is looking for the keys by their value. You have 7 keys  with the value of `1`. The first of which is `month`, hence that gets repeated a further 6 times. How you fix this depends on what you're trying to do, which isn't clear, as populating `arr` seems to serve no purpose; you already have access to the values, the keys and them together as an object via `data[0]`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am trying to get all the keys that have string values and out of what is left I want to find all the date corresponding keys.

Comment: I have added that in the description

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, is there a nother way to do that?

Comment: There's no way to do that just from detecting the variable type, given the sample data. You could use the keys, but then you need to know what they are before runtime, which I'm guessing you don't, otherwise this is 4 lines of code.

Comment: True, and this is dynamic data in which the keys and values change with every run

Comment: In that case I'd suggest looking for a number greater than `946684800` in the values. This is the epoch timestamp for 01/01/2000. Then you can convert that to a date and pull the d/m/y from it. You could use a larger number if the entities you're dealing with are even more recent. Obviously, this is not infallible, but it depends on your expected dataset

Comment: @noob are the values and keys received in the correct order? If the order of both arrays is guaranteed, you can construct the object and simply use the key/value pairs

Comment: @alt146, yes they are. How do I do what you are saying?

Comment: @alt146 OPs comment: `this is dynamic data in which the keys and values change with every run`

Comment: @noob see my updated answer for a simple code to construct an object out of two arrays

Answer (score 2):

"find" finds the first occurrence, so every time it looks for the key for "1" the first key with value 1 it finds is "month"

month is printed once on the second line (after Year) , and then you have another six  keys with value 1's in your object

Simple code to create an object out of two arrays:

```
var keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
var values = [11, 22, 33]

var result = {};
keys.forEach((key, i) => result[key] = values[i]);
```